# How do I repeat the onClick text input function?

Tags: javascript, replace, onclick, var

I am new to Javascript. I am trying to replace the word "test" with input in the text input field. The code seems to be replacing the text the first time around but I want it to do it every time a new value is entered in the text field and the button is pressed.

```
       <p id="replacetext">
               1. Test </br>
               2. Test </br>
               3. Test </br>
       </p>
   <input id="myInput" type="text"/>
        ​
   <script>
            function onClick() {
                var replacetest =    document.getElementById("myInput").value;
                var str = document.getElementById("replacetext").innerHTML; 
                str = str.replace(/Test/g, replacetest);
                document.getElementById("replacetext").innerHTML = str;
                console.log(replacetext)
            }
        </script>
<button onclick="onClick()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not keeping track of old value (i.e you are replacing Test by input value but next time there is not "Test" string left  to replace )
try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dzr8n9vh/

```
<p id="replacetext">
               1. Test </br>
               2. Test </br>
               3. Test </br>
       </p>
   <input id="myInput" type="text"/>
   <script>
            var oldValue  = 'Test';
            function onClick() {
                var replacetest =    document.getElementById("myInput").value;
                var str = document.getElementById("replacetext").innerHTML; 
                var re = new RegExp(oldValue,"g");
                oldValue =replacetest
                str = str.replace(re, replacetest);
                str = str.replace("Event", "Purchase");

                document.getElementById("replacetext").innerHTML = str;
            }
        </script>
<button onclick="onClick()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script, you continue to replace the string "Text" on the second call even though it's already been changed on the first call to the value of the input.

What you need to do is remember the previous input's value at the end of the previous call (the prevValue variable), then replace that with the newly inputted value in the current call. Since you can't just use a variable in a regular expression, you have to convert it to a regex.

```html
<p id="replacetext">
    1. Test </br>
    2. Test </br>
    3. Test </br>
</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" /> ​
<script>
    // Set scope of variable outside of function
    var prevValue = "Test"

    function onClick() {
        var replacetext = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        var str = document.getElementById("replacetext").innerHTML;

        // Convert the variable to use it in the regular expression
        var regex = new RegExp(prevValue, 'g');
        str = str.replace(regex, replacetext);

        str = str.replace("Event", "Purchase");
        document.getElementById("replacetext").innerHTML = str;
        console.log(replacetext);

        // Update the previous variable
        prevValue = replacetext;
    }
</script>
<button onclick="onClick()">Submit</button>
```

Hopefully this works for you!